# How do we define multiple modules with the new NDK gradle based builder?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm attempting to learn and try using the new Android Studio gradle based ndk build support.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to define PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY ndk modules so that my main ndk module can use it. I have these setup using Android.mk but can't figure out how to convert that to gradle. :/

```
// SHARED LIBRARY
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "skia_android"
    cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/skia/skia/out/config/android-nexus_4/Debug/lib/libskia_android.so")}".toString()
    cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/skia/skia/include/core")}".toString()
    cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/skia/skia/include/utils")}".toString()
    cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/skia/skia/include/gpu")}".toString()
    cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/skia/skia/include/private")}".toString()
    ldLibs += ["EGL", "GLESv2"]
    stl    = "c++_static"
}

// MAIN LIBRARY
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "smasher"
    cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/smasher/include")}".toString()
    cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/smasher/src")}".toString()
    cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/smasher")}".toString()
    ldLibs += ["skia_android", "log", "android", "EGL", "GLESv2"]
    stl    = "c++_static"
    abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update (Feb '16):** the *experimantal* plugin allows native modules now! Not in the main, yet.

---

Unfortunately this is not supported by current gradle plugins. Specifically, currently there is no way to define native-only modules. I recommend to keep the traditional **Android.mk** which does this job reliably.

The trick is to disable the regular NDK build tasks, and inject a `buildNative` task instead:

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def ndkBuild = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir') + '/ndk-build'

import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
    ndkBuild += '.cmd'
}

task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    commandLine '$ndkBuild', 'NDK_PROJECT_PATH="$jniSrc/..'
}

task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
    commandLine '$ndkBuild', 'clean', 'NDK_PROJECT_PATH="$jniSrc/..'
}

clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'

tasks.all {
    task ->
        if (task.name.startsWith('compile') && task.name.contains('MainC')) {
            task.enabled = false
        }
        if (task.name.startsWith('link')) {
            task.enabled = false
        }
        if (task.name.endsWith("SharedLibrary") ) {
            task.dependsOn buildNative
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'm seeing the following error:

Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:cleanNative FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:cleanNative'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '$ndkBuild''

Comment: @Jona: there may be more info in the gradle log. Anyways, make sure that the **`$ndkBuild`** and **`jniSrc`** are correct. The easiest way to check may be to add `println("$ndkBuild")` and `println("$jniSrc")` to **cleanNative** task.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help. I really like this since I can continue to use Android.mk and have the syntax highlighting going. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the native standalone plugin. Just make sure you put the different libraries in different sub-projects as the experimental plugin does not support multiple modules in the same project (which is odd, because the native gradle plugins do).

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

```
root
+ lib -> apply plugin: 'com.android.model.native'
+ app -> apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
model {
    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                dependencies {
                    project ":lib" 
                    // optional: 
                    // buildType "debug" productFlavor "flavor" linkage "static"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do exactly this, but the documentation was not enough to make it work. And besides, my lib folder is included in my project app folder. Would you know where may I grab an example on achieving this? Thanks in advance